# image dimension validation in angular 6

Tags: angular, file-upload

How to validate dimensions of image on upload.uploading images should be of 100 x 100 size.

**Upload.ts**

```
 onFileChange(event) {
     let reader = new FileReader();
     if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
       let file = event.target.files[0];
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       reader.onload = () => {
          this.imagePreview = reader.result;
          this.employee.photo = reader.result.split(",")[1];
     };
    }
 }
```

**Upload.html**

```
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="file" id="avatar" 
            (change)="onFileChange($event)" #fileInput name="photo">
             <p style="color: red">photo should be 100 x 100 size</p>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

onFileChange(event) {
     let reader = new FileReader();
     if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
       let file = event.target.files[0];

       const img = new Image();
       img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL( file );

       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       reader.onload = () => {

         const width = img.naturalWidth,
         const height = img.naturalHeight;

         window.URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );

         if( width !== 100 && height !== 100 ) {
            this.error = "photo should be 100 x 100 size"
         }
         this.imagePreview = reader.result;
         this.employee.photo = reader.result.split(",")[1];
     };
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

[This answer works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53441088/8389728)
 but sometimes it returns 0 height and width and this is because image not gets loaded. 
I solve this problem by simply using setTimeout-

```
let reader = new FileReader();
if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
  let file = event.target.files[0];

  let img = new Image();

  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL( file );
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const width = img.naturalWidth;
      const height = img.naturalHeight;

      window.URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );
      console.log(width + '*' + height);
      if ( width !== 64 && height !== 64 ) {
        alert('photo should be 64 x 64 size');
        form.reset();
      } else {
        this.imgURL = reader.result;
      }
    }, 2000);
      };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reader.onload()` function like below.

```
reader.onload = () => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
        console.log(img.width);
        console.log(img.height);
        // Here you can make use prevention code like shown alert
    };
    img.src = reader.result; // The data URL 
};
```